# angular material md-select select default first value

Tags: angular, pipe, material-design, ngfor

How to get default first option as selected when data comes from pipe?

```
<md-select formControlName="key">
   <md-option *ngFor="let elem of (elements | TesxtFilter) ; let i = index"  [value]="elem .value">
        {{ elem.name }}
   </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: I found out how, Check my update. I will fetch the documentation so I can also link it for you to review. Have a nice day! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the index:

```
<md-option *ngFor="let elem of (elements | TesxtFilter) ; let i = index"  [value]="elem .value" [selected]="i === 0">
```

You are basically saying that if the `index` is **0** *(first option)* it should be selected.

You can select an option by using this: `[selected]="condition"`.

**Update 1:**

I think that the value of the select is the one that determines which option is actually selected. And anyway, in my opinion, you should always have the `ngModel` in your `select`. Try this code and let me know please:

In your html:

```
<md-select formControlName="key" [(ngModel)]="myDefaultOption">
   <md-option *ngFor="let elem of (elements | TesxtFilter) ; let i = index"  [value]="elem.value">
        {{ elem.name }}
   </md-option>
</md-select>
```

In your component:

```
myDefaultOption = this.elements[0].value; // Here you should select the first option's value of the array of options for the select
```

If you want to see the documentation: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/select/select.md#getting-and-setting-the-select-value

Basically, normal Angular 2 procedures *(first part of my answer)* don't work.

What you need to do *(I'm explaining code above)* is to store the default **value** in your component and reference it in a `ngModel` in your `md-select`. Then the selected value will be the `md-option` that has as a `value` the one referenced in the `ngModel` in your `md-select`.

**Update 2:**

As said in comment, if you need to have as a selected option *the first option of the filtered by pipe collection of items*, then you should apply the `@Pipe` in the component, and then manage that filtered collection.

```
import { TextFilter } from './text-filter.pipe';
class MyClass {

  filteredElements;
  constructor(private textFilter: TextFilter) {
      this.filteredElements = this.textFilter.transform(this.elements); // We apply the pipe to the 'elements' collection
      myDefaultOption = this.elements[0].value; // We select the first option of the filtered 'elements' collection
  }  
}
```

In your HTML:

```
<md-select formControlName="key" [(ngModel)]="myDefaultOption">
   <md-option *ngFor="let elem of filteredElements; let i = index"  [value]="elem.value">
        {{ elem.name }}
   </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I have an error " Can't bind to 'selected' since it isn't a known property of 'md-option'"
[attr.selected] -> doesn't cause an error but it doesn't work

Comment: @Vero I see. Try what the code from my update. Let's how it goes. I was researching a bit in the depths of `md-select`.

Comment: elements is an origin array (before filtering). 
What if pipe filter rejects first element of elements? 
elements[0] won't be in options of a <md-select>, elements[1] might be first

Comment: In that case, you could use the pipe inside your component, store it in a variable and use that *"piped"* variable for your `md-select`.

Comment: @Vero Check my second update. There you find an example of your code applying the `@Pipe` to the `elements` object, then selecting the **default option** *(the one that we want to be selected)* and then we just use this filtered object in the template. So instead of using the `@Pipe` in the template we used it in the component.